# Creating an Object from an Array of Objects with references to parent Object

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the confusing title... I don't know a better summery.

I have an Array of Objects. Some of these Objects have a reference to it's parent Object. Something like that:

```
data: 
[
  {id: 2, parent: 1},
  {id: 1},
  {id: 3, parent: 1},
  {id: 5, parent: 3},
  {id: 4, parent: 3},
  {id: 6, parent: 2} 

]
```

What I want to do, is creating an Object out of this Array where the child objects are nested inside their parents. Like that:

```
data: {
  id: 1,
  children: [
    {
      id:2,
      children: [
        {id: 6}
      ]
    },
    {
      id:3,
      children: [
        {id: 4},
        {id: 5}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know a smart way of doing this? 
I know I have to itterate through every Object of this Array and check if there is a parent. But how can I actually create this Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure it's the best way to do it, but at least it's one way to do it.

1. First loop over the nodes:

   - Put the nodes in a lookup table by their `id` (`nodes`).
   - Find the `root` node (the single node with no `parent`).
2. Second loop (with the lookup table complete):

   - Check if the `node` has a `parent` (true for every node except the `root`).
   - Get the `parent` node by looking up the id in the lookup table.
   - Get the `parent.children` array, or create it if it doesn't exist yet.
   - Add this `node` to that array.
   - Remove the `parent` property of this `node`.

Note that this changes the original node objects in your `data` object. This is intentional, since the tree is built by storing references to other nodes in parent nodes. If you need to keep the original nodes in `data` intact, you should clone the node objects while building the lookup table. For example, you could add `node = $.extend({}, node);` as first line in the lookup `forEach` loop (when using jQuery).

Here's an implementation and a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/SnC7r/):

```
var data = [
  {id: 2, parent: 1},
  {id: 1},
  {id: 3, parent: 1},
  {id: 5, parent: 3},
  {id: 4, parent: 3},
  {id: 6, parent: 2}
];

// Node lookup table
var nodes = {};
// Root node
var root = null;
// Fill lookup table and find root
data.forEach(function(node) {
    nodes[node.id] = node;
    // Assuming only one root node
    if(!("parent" in node)) {
        root = node;
    }
});
// Build tree
for(var id in nodes) {
    var node = nodes[id];
    if("parent" in node) {
        // Add to children of parent
        var parent = nodes[node.parent];
        (parent.children = parent.children || []).push(node);
        // Remove parent property (optional)
        delete node.parent;
    }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(root));
```